# Custom theme in Android

Tags: android, android-theme

I am new with Android and got kinda stuck with theming my app. I use the Navigation Drawer Layout so I need to use backwards compatible theme. My theme is the following:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mycustomactionbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mycustomactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#6FBC2C</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

However, when I run the code the color of my action bar remains the same, but I don't get any error. How could I debug such a thing? There is no error at build time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the current AppCompat library (version 21.+, with the Material theme), you can use the following code to re-color your theme.

You can specify the color directly in your style. But I prefer to use a separate definition for the colors, so you can use them in your code also.

```
<color name="primary">@color/material_brown_500</color>
<color name="primaryDark">@color/material_brown_700</color>
<color name="accent">@color/material_pink_A200</color>

<style name="My.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>


<color name="material_brown_500">#795548</color>
<color name="material_brown_700">#5D4037</color>
<color name="material_pink_A200">#FF4081</color>
```